# Create nested json object using jquery

Tags: javascript, .net, json, json.net, getjson

Using json object not from array.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var editeditems = {}; 
    var address = {};
    var firstName;
    var lasteName; 
    $('#btnJson').click(function () { 
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
            address["street"] = i; 
            address["city"] = i; 
        } 
        editeditems["FirstName"] = "mehul"; 
        editeditems["LastName"] = "gohel"; 
        editeditems["Address"] = address; 
        $('#txtVal').text(JSON.stringify(editeditems)); 
    }); 
});
```

I am using this code and get output of:

```
{
   "firstName": "Mehul",
   "lasteName": "Gohel",
   "address": [
      {
         "Street": 0,
         "City": 0
      },
      {
         "Street": 1,
         "City": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please explain your question, and also include the codes you have tried so far. That will help people to understand your question. Thanks

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
var editeditems = {}; var address = {};var firstName;var lasteName;
  $('#btnJson').click(function () {
   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
              address["street"] = i;
              address["city"] = i;
           }
           editeditems["FirstName"] = "mehul";
           editeditems["LastName"] = "gohel";
            editeditems["Address"] = address;
           $('#txtVal').text(JSON.stringify(editeditems));
          });
    }); 
I am using this code and get output of {"FirstName":"mehul","LastName":"gohel","Address":{"street":2,"city":2}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#btnJson').click(function () { 
    var jsonObj = {}; 
    var addressArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
        var address = {}
        address.street = i; 
        address.city = i; 
        addressArray.push(address);
    } 

    jsonObj.FirstName = "mehul"; 
    jsonObj.LastName = "gohel"; 
    jsonObj.Address = addressArray;  

    $('#txtVal').text(JSON.stringify(jsonObj)); 
  });
});
```

Another one:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#btnJson').click(function () { 
    var jsonObj = {
      "FirstName":"mehul",
      "LastName":"gohel",
      "Address":[]
    }; 

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
        var address = {}
        address.street = i; 
        address.city = i; 
        jsonObj.Address.push(address);
    } 

    $('#txtVal').text(JSON.stringify(jsonObj)); 
  });
});
```

And you will get this result:

```
{
  "FirstName":"mehul",
  "LastName":"gohel",
  "Address":[
    {"street":0,"city":0},
    {"street":1,"city":1},
    {"street":2,"city":2}
  ]
}
```

Comment: The second solution is just the same with different approach.